# Gparted live CD UI crashed, gpartedbin still running. Anything I can do?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted

I'm running Gparted live CD v0.15.0-1 on a production file server (after having tested 
successfully on a similarly-partitioned test server).

The actions I wanted to do are:

1. delete /dev/sda5 (0.99GB)
2. delete /dev/sda6 (9.99GB)
3. Shrink /dev/sda7 by 14GB from 1600GB to 1586GB (about 50% used)
4. Move all logical partitions (sda3 till sda7) to the back of the extended partition (sda2)
5. Shrink the extended partition (sda2) in the beginning
6. Expand sda1 to 50GB

The partitions are all NTFS formatted (it's a Win2K8R2 server).

I started this operation last Friday, and by the speed it was progressing estimated it would take about a week.
Now, some days ago, the UI of Gparted seems to have crashed, I only have grey window without any progress indicators.

When I run 'top' however, I can see the 'grpartedbin' process using 100% CPU, HDD leds are still very busy.
So I'm quite confident that Gparted is still working on the scheduled actions, however I can't monitor the progress.
Any ideas what I could try? Is there any way to restart the UI? Or perhaps I log file I could monitor for any progress?

Comment: *The partitions are all NTFS formatted (it's a Win2K8R2 server).* So you didn't use the built in Disk Management MMC snap-in because ... ?

Comment: Because it doesn't allow shrinking and moving partitions...

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731894.aspx "Moving" can be achieved as well, by combining an extend and shrink.